# R 3.6.3 dose not launch in coexistence environment with R 4.0.4

Tags: r

I can not launch R.app on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). When I launch it, the following error message was returned, and I can not do anything. But when I launch Rstudio.app, I have no problem with R 3.6.3.

Note that, before this trouble, I tried coexistantce/switching of multiple versions of R. First I uninstalled R (ver 4.0.3) through homebrew (brew uninstall --cask r). So R has been deleted completely. Then I installed R 3.6.3 and R 4.0.4 through their official installers. Also I installed Rswitch.

Rswitch switches R versions correctly now. After switching from ver 3.6.3, R 4.0.4 launches with no problem through both R.app and Rstudio.app.

Probably, it seems the "stringsAsFactors" problem relating to version 4.0. But version 4.0.4 is ok in launching in my case. This trouble occurs with R 3.6.3. Does anyone know about this kind of problem?

Thank you.

```
警告メッセージ (warning): 
 options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE) で: 
  'options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)' is deprecated and will be disabled

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2e9e8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: initMethodDispatch(where)
 2: fun(libname, pkgname)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 7: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
 8: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
13: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly, mask.ok = mask.ok,     exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only, attach.required = attach.required)
14: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
15: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
16: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
17: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly,     mask.ok = mask.ok, exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only,     attach.required = attach.required), error = function(e) e)
18: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
19: .OptRequireMethods()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: R 4.0.x  (x = 0, 1, 2, 3) has some bugs on with asian characters, which should be fixed in the 4.0.5 version. Maybe updating to 4.0.4 will fix the problem as well, otherwise version 4.0.5 is scheduled for the 31'st of March and "should" fix your problem. I am assuming the problem is only vaguely related to the `stringAsFactors` message.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you very much for replying. OK, I wait for newer versions!